# Suitable File Structure for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

First things first, this is not a coding error question.

its somewhat of a discussion type. Actually I followed a file-structure for last two years, and now i want to get people review or suggestions on that file structure

generally in CI the following structure in maintained within the application folder

```
root
-----------
     |___application
           |____ config
           |____ controllers
           |____ models
           |____ views
           ................
           ................
           |____ .htaccess
```

now I personally use this structure

```
root
-----------
 |___application
      |___front
      |     |____ config
      |     |____ controllers
      |     |____ models
      |     |____ views
      |     ................
      |     ................
      |     |____ .htaccess 
      |
      |___admin
      |     |____ config
      |     |____ controllers
      |     |____ models
      |     |____ views
      |     ................
      |     ................
      |     |____ .htaccess
```

Now i have only one model which has the basic shareable functions. So i made two duplicate copies and put one in

`application/front/models` and the other one in the `application/admin/models`

Now the application/front folder is called by the seeting in the index.php file in the root folder

```
$application_folder = 'application/front';
```

Now to access the admin panel, we need to access the application/admin folder which is done by the following way

i made a duplicate of the index.php(renamed it as admin.php) file and put it in the root folder.
Then i made the change `$application_folder = 'application/admin';`

so if a url is like this

```
abc.com/admin.php/reports
```

then it calls the `reports controller` inside the `application/admin/controllers` folder

So all i want to know from you is that is this file-structure ok and shall i continue with this??

or i should use some other means

Comment: Looks OK to me, but maybe you need to put common models in a central place and not duplicate them.

Comment: Try to make module for each
https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules

Comment: You can try [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc) to organize or code.

Answer (score 0):

One very common solution to this is to set a new "Application Package."

In 2.x.0 this is not well documented, but you can see about it here:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Basically add a shared path, called `shared/` then add `shared/models`. To load that simply do:

```
$this->load->add_package_path(dirname(APPPATH).'shared/');
$this->load->model('whatever');
```

You can probably switch out APPPATH with FCPATH or something. It's been a year or two since I've used CodeIgniter for anything, but this is how I used to do it.